# Special characters in zookeeper after updating Zookeeper offsets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I update the offset of zookeeper in my own program with the code as below:

```
val zkClient= new ZkClient(zookeeperConnect)

val zkPath = s"${zkTopicPath}/${osr.partition}"

ZkUtils.updatePersistentPath(zkClient, zkPath,osr.untilOffset.toString)
```

The program ran with no error , but when I access the zookeeper path:

> /consumers/testgroup0/offsets/tests0/0 "

there are some special characters before the offset value as shown below, **why does it happen and how to fix it ? Thanks a lot!**

[image: special chars in zookeeper]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD0fG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I compiled the program with kafka 0.8.2,  scala 2.10.1, jdk 1.7

I ran the program with kafka 0.9.0, scala 2.11.7, jre 1.8, zookeeper 3.4.6